# Auto increment column by condition

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like the following

```
ID - Project - Entry - Value
int   int       int    varchar
```

`ID` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Now I want `Entry` to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` according to `Project`. Meaning for each record/row with `Project`=`1`, `ENTRY` is auto-incrementing. The requirement is that `ENTRY` is always `+ 1` according to the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since auto increment is triggered inside the db via table definition, you cannot do this based on a condition

Comment: So I'd need to do this programmatically?

Comment: What purpose does ID serve being in the table? Why isn't your primary key Project and Entry as a combined key? Often people put an auto increment column in as the primary key because they think they have to rather than use a natural key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write an `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to manage auto increment for project id, e.g.:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER entry_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
   ON table FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   DECLARE entry int;
   SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Entry), 0) + 1 INTO entry WHERE project = NEW.project;
   SET NEW.Entry = entry;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [Triggers](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/). A trigger is basically an SQL code executes just before or just after an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE event occurs on a database table.
Using triggers, you can update the Entry field based on the value of the Project field.